# Redux and data fetching

Tags: react-redux

I am a newbie to React and Redux hope the folks here can help me. I am trying to make 2 api calls as shown below. However only the first api call seem to get run so my rootCategories end up always being set to null. How can I ensure second api call also get executed before state being changed?

### Reducer

```js
 export const categoryListReducer = (state = {categories: [], rootCategories: []}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CATEGORY_LIST_REQUEST:
            return {loading: true, categories: [], rootCategories: []}
        case ROOT_CATEGORY_LIST_REQUEST:                
            return {loading: true, rootCategories: []}
        case CATEGORY_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, loading: false, categories: action.payload[0], rootCategories: action.payload[1]}
        case ROOT_CATEGORY_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, loading: false, rootCategories: action.payload} 
        case ROOT_CATEGORY_LIST_FAIL:
            return {loading: false, error: action.payload}       
        case CATEGORY_LIST_FAIL:
            return {loading: false, error: action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

### Action

```js
export const listCategories = (breadcrumbs) => async(dispatch) => {
  try {
    //fire off first reducer and load off empty array of products
    dispatch({
      type: CATEGORY_LIST_REQUEST
    })

    const apiEndPoint = breadcrumbs ?
      `/api/products/categories/${breadcrumbs}/` :
      '/api/products/categories/'

    const {
      data
    } = await axios(apiEndPoint)
    const {
      data2
    } = await axios('/api/products/categories/')

    dispatch({
      type: CATEGORY_LIST_SUCCESS,
      payload: [data, data2],
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error  ' + error)
    dispatch({
      type: CATEGORY_LIST_FAIL,
      payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.response.data
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
    if (data & data2) {
      dispatch({
        type: CATEGORY_LIST_SUCCESS,
        payload: [data, data2]
      })
    }
```

Now, the dispatch is only executed if both const are set.

EDIT:

I found this [post](https://www.storyblok.com/tp/how-to-send-multiple-requests-using-axios) about how Axios seems to have its own way to fetch two URLs at once, like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
 
let one = "https://api.storyblok.com/v1/cdn/stories/health?version=published&token=wANpEQEsMYGOwLxwXQ76Ggtt"
let two = "https://api.storyblok.com/v1/cdn/datasources/?token=wANpEQEsMYGOwLxwXQ76Ggtt"
 
const requestOne = axios.get(one);
const requestTwo = axios.get(two);
 
axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
  const responseOne = responses[0]
  const responseTwo = responses[1]
  // use/access the results 
})).catch(errors => {
  // react on errors.
})
```

Comment: I tried this but reducer does not get executed at all. So my categories and rootCategories are set to an empty list. I don't understand why the second axios call does not get executed.

Comment: Are you sure, that the second axios call isn't executed, or could it be that it doesn't return anything? (Just to be sure) Could this [post](https://www.storyblok.com/tp/how-to-send-multiple-requests-using-axios) help you?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I followed the example in the post and got it to work.